# Calibre Startup Error : Bus Name already exists

Tags: dbus, calibre

I am unable to launch calibre application. I tried re-installing it. Yet, it still gives me the following message every time.

```
calibre, version 2.55.0
ERROR: Startup error: There was an error during calibre startup. Parts of calibre may not function. Click Show details to learn more.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/main.py", line 276, in initialize_db_stage2
    self.start_gui(db)
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/main.py", line 216, in start_gui
    main.initialize(self.library_path, db, self.listener, self.actions)
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/ui.py", line 261, in initialize
    self.system_tray_icon = factory(app_id='com.calibre-ebook.gui').create_system_tray_icon(parent=self, title='calibre')
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/dbus_export/widgets.py", line 232, in create_system_tray_icon
    ans = StatusNotifierItem(parent=parent, title=title, app_id=self.app_id, category=category)
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/dbus_export/tray.py", line 44, in __init__
    self.dbus_api = StatusNotifierItemAPI(self, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/dbus_export/tray.py", line 114, in __init__
    self.dbus_name = BusName(self.name, bus=bus, do_not_queue=True)
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/utils/dbus_service.py", line 238, in __new__
    raise NameExistsException(name)
NameExistsException: Bus name already exists: org.kde.StatusNotifierItem-3230-1
```

Need help to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install it via apt-get?  I've found Calibre to be fairly finicky and fragile.

I've once before remedied the error pasted above by manually reinstalling the `python-dbus` package, but that same fix did not work on a subsequent re-appearance of that error.

I finally followed the developers' advice and installed it directly:

```
sudo -v && wget -nv -O- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/master/setup/linux-installer.py | sudo python -c "import sys; main=lambda:sys.stderr.write('Download failed\n'); exec(sys.stdin.read()); main()"
```

This has led to [*mostly*] trouble-free installations (on Ubuntu and OpenSUSE).

There are alternate installation options on the official install page (in addition to the one listed above):

[Calibre for Download for Linux](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux)

This page states:

> Please do not use your distribution provided calibre package, as those
>   are often buggy/outdated. Instead use the Binary install described
>   below.

I initially ignored this advice, since I typically prefer to install packages from the default package managers.  But in the case of Calibre, I've burned a great deal of time troubleshooting and fixing issues that were ultimately avoided by following the official installation directions.

If you **did** install via apt, make sure to remove (uninstall) before attempting the above.